# Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor with inheritance

Tags: java, junit, constructor, junit4, super

I have my parent abstract JUnitTest class:

```
public abstract class RestWSTest
{

  public RestWSTest()
  {
  }

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception
  {
    ...
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then I would like to have a class that extends `RestWSTest`, like this:

```
public class RestWSCreateGroupTest extends RestWSTest
{

  public RestWSCreateGroupTest()
  {
    super();
  }

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception
  {
    super(); -->   *Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor*
    ...
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception
  {
    super(); -->   *Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor*
    ...
  }

  @Test
  public void testCreateGroup()
  {
  ...
  }
 }
```

Why do I get the error message? I have a constructor and there I call `super()`, so I don't really know what to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `public void setUp()` is not a constructor. You can not call `super();` inside it. I think you intend `super.setUp();`

Answer (score 2):

**You can't use the super() call outside the constructor methods.**

In other words, setUp() and tearDown() are methods and they are NOT constrcutors, so you can't use super() call.

**Rather, you can access/invoke the super class methods using the syntax: super.mySuperClassMethod();**

So change your code as below:

```
public class RestWSCreateGroupTest extends RestWSTest
{

  public RestWSCreateGroupTest()
  {
    super();
  }

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception
  {
    super.setUp();
    ...
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception
  {
    super.tearDown();
    ...
  }

  @Test
  public void testCreateGroup()
  {
  ...
  }
 }
```

For more details refer the below link:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html